# Batch file to determine websites in IE

Tags: windows, batch-file, internet-explorer

Is there a piece of code which can be used in a batch file to determine if firstly IE is open, and if so which websites are open in the tab(s)?

I am needing to force close IE when a user locks their PC, and if a specific website is open.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try for this batch file :

```dos
@echo off
Title Checking Running Process and Get their command lines
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Mode 90,25 & color 0A
Set "ProcessName=iexplore.exe"
Set "String2Search=facebook"
Call :CheckRunning !ProcessName!
If /I "%flag%"=="True" (
    color 0A
    echo %flag%
    Call :GetCommandLine !ProcessName!
    echo(
    Call :CheckString_in_URL "%String2Search%"
) else (
    color 0C
    echo %flag%
    echo !ProcessName! is not running !
    pause>nul & exit
)
Exit
::********************************************************************************************************
:CheckRunning <ProcessName>
Set "ProcessName=%1"
tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %ProcessName%" 2>nul |find /i "%ProcessName%" >nul
If not errorlevel 1 ( Set "flag=True" ) else ( Set "flag=False" )
Exit /b 
::********************************************************************************************************
:GetCommandLine <ProcessName>
Set "ProcessCmd="
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%P in ('wmic process where caption^="%~1" get commandline /format:value ^| findstr /I "%~1" ^| find /I /V "%~nx0" 2^>nul') do (
    Set "ProcessCmd=%%P"
    echo !ProcessCmd!
)
Exit /b
::******************************************************************************************************
:Kill <ProcessName>
Taskkill /IM "%~1" /F>nul 2>&1
Exit /b
::******************************************************************************************************
:CheckString_in_URL <String2Search>
set "String2Search=%~1"
(
echo Set objFso = CreateObject^("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)    
echo Set colShWindows = CreateObject^("shell.application"^).Windows
echo For Each w In colShWindows
echo    If objFso.GetFileName^(LCase^(w.FullName^)^) = "iexplore.exe" Then
echo        WScript.Echo w.LocationURL
echo    End If
echo Next
)>"%Temp%\iexplore_tabs.vbs"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%Temp%\iexplore_tabs.vbs"') do (
    set /a index+=1
    set "URL[!index!]=%%a"
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) do (
    echo !URL[%%i]! | find /I "%String2Search%">nul && ( 
        echo Found this string "%String2Search%" in the URL "!URL[%%i]!"
        echo(
        echo Did you want to kill this process "!ProcessName!" Y/N ?
        Set /p "Answer="
            If /I "!Answer!"=="Y" ( Call :Kill "!ProcessName!" ) else ( exit )
        ) || (
            echo No string like "%String2Search%" found in "!URL[%%i]!"
            Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul
        )
)
exit /b 
::******************************************************************************************************
```

I'm grateful to aGerman that give me the idea of ***[how to enumerate the URLs of the InternetExplorer tabs](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=57574#p57574)***

Comment: Hi Hackoo, this batch just determines if IE is open, i can't see where i would ask it to determine if a specific website is open. Is there somewhere i can input this? I want it to let me know if a website is open in a tab within IE. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks every so much. People like you make Stackoverflow. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, apologies for adding to this, but is it possible to prevent the code running if specific text in the string exists? i.e. If "LogOff" (string3)' or "Login" (string4) is present, then the taskkill code won't run? I have tried different methods, and can't get it to work, as each of the string 3 and string4 contain string2, if that makes sense. Thanks in advance